# iOS newsstand read pdf horizontally

Tags: ios, pdf, newsstand-kit

i want to make a newsstand application and i found an example named howtomakeamagazineapp. but in this example it uses QL and there is no chance to read pdf horizontally. i want to scroll horizontally in pdf viewer. is there any chance to integrate another framework or class to this one or is there any chance make this example work horizontally?

the read issue method is:

```
-(void)readIssue:(Issue *)issue {
QLPreviewController *preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
preview.delegate=self;
preview.dataSource=self;
urlOfReadingIssue=[[issue contentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"magazine.pdf"];
NSLog(@"%@",issue.contentURL);
[self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: And you tried what? What code did you write to attempt to do this in any way?